# How to store tuples of data in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, data-structures, collections, tuples

I would like some way to hard code information in C# as follows:

```
1423, General 
5298, Chiro 
2093, Physio 
9685, Dental 
3029, Optics
```

I would like to then refer to this data as follows:

```
"The description for category 1423 is " & MyData.GetDescription[1423] 
"The id number for General is " & MyData.GetIdNumber("General")
```

What would be the best way to do this in C#?

Comment: What's wrong with a Dictionary?

Comment: @DGibbs Is that available in C#?

Comment: [Absolutely](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Well you *could* use `Tuple<int, string>` - but I'd suggest creating a class to store the two values:

```
public sealed class Category
{
    private readonly int id;
    public int Id { get { return id; } }

    private readonly string description;
    public string Description { get { return description; } }

    public Category(int id, string description)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }

    // Possibly override Equals etc
}
```

Then for lookup purposes, you could either have a `Dictionary<string, Category>` for description lookups and a `Dictionary<int, Category>` for ID lookups - or if you were confident that the number of categories would stay small, you could just use a `List<Category>`.

The benefits of having a named type for this over using just a `Tuple` or simple `Dictionary<string, int>` and `Dictionary<int, string>` are:

- You have a concrete type you can pass around, use in your data model etc
- You won't end up confusing a `Category` with any *other* data type which is logically just an `int` and a `string`
- Your code will be clearer to read when it uses `Id` and `Description` properties than `Item1` and `Item2` from `Tuple<,>`.
- If you need to add another property later, the changes are minimal.

Comment: Most of times I found myself to prefer a custom class over Dictionary. It is easy to extend and often Dictionary just can't fulfill my requirement (even for combobox text->value). In which situation does Dictionary is prefered?

Comment: @Fendy: I generally use a Dictionary when I *just* want a collection with hash-based lookup. It's not really clear what sort of situation you're thinking of.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

```
var items = new Dictionary<int, string>();
items.Add(1423, "General");
...

var valueOf1423 = items[1423];
var keyOfGeneral = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "General").Key;
```

The example above will throw an exception if there's no item with value "General". To prevent this you could wrap the Dictionary in a custom class and check if the entry exists and returns whatever you need.

Note that the value is not unique, a Dictonary allows you to store the same values with different keys.

A wrapper class could look something like this:

```
public class Category {
    private Dictionary<int, string> items = new Dictionary<int,, string>();

    public void Add(int id, string description) {
        if (GetId(description <> -1)) {
            // Entry with description already exists. 
            // Handle accordingly to enforce uniqueness if required.
        } else {
            items.Add(id, description);
        }
    }

    public string GetDescription(int id) {
        return items[id];
    }

    public int GetId(string description) {
        var entry = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == description);
        if (entry == null) 
            return -1;
        else
            return entry.Key;
    }
}
```